# How to create Attractive Side Bar Menus at Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

How the attractive sidebar menus can be created at Delphi  as shown below in attached image?

[image]

TCAtegoryPanelGroup and TCategoryPanel works out but in order add menu items to TCategoryPanel and make it stylish and attractive like one shown in fig is complicated. While TJvXpBar is something what I want but at background I want a Panel which would distinguish left part from right one as shown in figure below as well as expand automatically when form is maximized at runtime.

http://s5.postimg.org/6e6dfb4sn/interface.jpg

I want to have GUI interface as shown above the form size in default 800 * 400 px as shown in the image above. Which panel should be used at the background of TJvXpBar (As shown in figure) so that when maximized at runtime (1366 * 768) background panel(strip) wont break from top to bottom.

(please check the link for interface image, cannot add image in edit mode)

Comment: as the question stands there are two possible close reasons `primarily opinion-based` and `off topic recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource `, perhaps you could try to reword the question.

Comment: Delphi Version is XE 4

Comment: As TLama suggested, you should use TCategoryPanelGroup, there is absolutely no need for any third party components here since you can achieve such results just by changing the properties of the CategoryPanelGroup. For all the sub commands you can use the TButtonGroup component as the child of the CategoryPanel or simply image buttons. You could even use VCL styles to really modify the CategoryPanelGroup in every way you see fit. Always avoid using 3rd party components, that is good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use side bar menus from [Jedi Project](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) or from [TMS components](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmspack.asp). As suggested by [TLama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama) you can use [TCategoryPanel](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCategoryPanel)

LE: Jedi Project has in its folder a megademo example(usually it is the path yourJediInstallFolder\jvcl\examples\JVCLMegaDemo). With that demo you can see how the controls look like. Then, you can choose what you believe it suite your needs(e.g TJvXPBarInformation)

[image]

Comment: There is also the [`TCategoryPanel`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCategoryPanel) shipped with newer versions of Delphi which allows you to create the expandable panels.

Comment: I dont have TCategoryPanel at my Tool Palete.There is TCategoryPanelGroup. I wonder if TCategoryPanelGroup is there then why not TCategoryPanel. I also have installed JEDI/JVCL but at JEDI/JVCL cannot find anything like sidebar menus at JVTools..

Comment: @NinadAvasare, TCategoryPanel is part of the TCategoryPanelGroup component. Right click on CategoryPanelGroup component while in design mode and click add Panel... This will insert a TCategoryPanel that you can use as a parent to other components.

Answer (score 5):

DevExpress has a [NavBar control](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExNavBar/).

[image: Explorer bars screenshot]